# Is there a maximum on Inquisition perks?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

According to some articles, there is no hard cap on character level in single-player (max is 20 for multiplayer), but rather some theoretical soft cap.

Is this the case for Influence? Do I only have so many Inquisition perks available in a playthrough or can I unlock all of them?

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to reach level 20 inquisition and couldn't get any more inquisition experience with the special items in Skyhold.